# Error "passing const List<int> as this argument discards qualifiers" within method definition

Tags: c++, this, constants

I am trying to make a dynamic list of general type T which has some operators overloaded for better manipulations. I have added some member functions for various accessibility and sorting kind of things also. In the function findAll(), I am getting an error:

> error: passing ‘`const List<int>`’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]"

in a different header file custom exception handling has be done. It will return an exception when the element of the list accessed is not found or searching is done outside the list size.

```
struct outOfScope : public exception {

const char * what () const throw () {

  return "Couldn't assign or retrieve value!, out of scope 
issue!\n";

}
};
```

I have already added constant keyword at the end of the function findAll, still the same error displays.

```
template<class T>
class List //will not work for a list of arrays, and can't be made a typedef of fixed size
//"typedef List<vector> tensor(3)" will not work
//you will have to rather use List<List<vector>>
{
    public:

    T *p = NULL;
    int s;//size
//public:
    //constructor
    List(){p=NULL; s=0;}


    List(int i)
    {
        s = i;
        if(p!=NULL)
        {
            delete [] p;
            p = NULL;
        }
        p = new T [s];
        if(!p)
        {
            throw pointerInitialization();
        }
    }

//copy constructor
    List(const List<T>& l)
    {
        if(p!=NULL)
        {
            delete [] p;
            p = NULL;
        }
        s = l.size();
        s = l.size();
        p = new T [s];  //Don't write in place of 'new T', p = l.p because
        //it will store value without the need to use for loop but destructor 'delete [] p' will delete it multiple times,
        //causing 'double delete error'

        if(!p)
        {
            throw pointerInitialization();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
        {
            p[i] = l.p[i];
        }
    }

    List(List<T>& l)
    {
        if(p!=NULL)
        {
            delete [] p;
            p = NULL;
        }
        s = l.size();
        s = l.size();
        p = new T [s];  //Don't write in place of 'new T', p = l.p because
        //it will store value without the need to use for loop but destructor 'delete [] p' will delete it multiple times,
        //causing 'double delete error'

        if(!p)
        {
            throw pointerInitialization();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
        {
            p[i] = l.p[i];
        }
    }





    void operator=(const List<T>& l)
    {
        if(p!=NULL)
        {
            delete [] p;
            p = NULL;
        }
        s = l.size();
        p = new T [s];
        if(!p)
        {
            throw pointerInitialization();
        }
        for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
        {
            p[i] = l.p[i];
        }
    }

    void operator=(List<T>& l)
    {
        if(p!=NULL)
        {
            delete [] p;
            p = NULL;
        }
        s = l.size();
        p = new T [s];
        if(!p)
        {
            throw pointerInitialization();
        }
        for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
        {
            p[i] = l.p[i];
        }
    }


    //member functions
    void setValues(int i);//can be used to reassign the variables any 


    T& operator[](int i)
    {
        if(i<s && i>=0)
        return p[i];

        else
        {
            throw outOfScope();
        }
    }

    int size(){return s;}

    void addAtEnd(T newEntry)//adding a node at the end of the list
    {
        s = s+1;
        T* newP = new T[s];// new pointer of one greater size is created
        newP[s-1] = newEntry;//at the last node, newEntry is added
        for(int i=0; i<s-1; i++)//for the rest of the entry, *newP copies data of the *p
        {
            newP[i] = p[i];
        }

        delete [] p;//deleting the memory pointed by the pointer p, doesn't mean p has lost its existence
        p = new T[s];//reassigning p to a new memory of size s(no need to use NULL before it as we are already
        //reassigning it again. Also don't write T* p = new T[s], it will create a different p, because now the
        //statement becomes a declaration type, there must not be two declarations of the same name p (once already
        //declared in member variable declaration of class List

        for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
        {
            p[i] = newP[i];
        }

        delete [] newP;
        newP = NULL;
    }

    int find(T value); //takes argument as the element of list, returns the location of list (counting zero as first node)


    List<int> findAll(T value) const//takes argument as the element of list, returns the location of list (counting zero as first node)
    {
        List<int>  locList;
        for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
        {
            if(p[i]==value)
            {
                locList.addAtEnd(i);
            }
        }

        if(locList.size() != 0)
            return locList;

        else
        {
                throw outOfScope();
        }
    }

    bool lookup(T value);



    //destructor
    ~List()
    {
        delete [] p;//means whenever destructor is called to destroy the object,
        //first of all, 'p' will delete the variable it is pointing to. Then the List obj will be destroyed
        p = NULL;
//      cout<<"\ndestructror is called! \n";
    }
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//macros
#define forAll(List, i)  for(int i=0; i<List.size(); i++)
```

Implementation code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>

int main()
{
List<int> rollNo(5);
int k=0;
rollNo[k++] = 2;
rollNo[k++] = 2;
rollNo[k++] = 3;
rollNo[k++] = 2;
rollNo[k++] = 3;

List<int> findList = rollNo.findAll(rollNo[2]);

forAll(findList, i)
cout<<findList[i]<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: To be a bit more specific than @Someprogrammerdude: Add the full error message to your code and indicates on which line it occurs. Provide the necessary members of `List` so that your code can be compiled (e.g., what are `s`  and `p`? `outOfScope`? And remove everything that's unecessary to avoid having a too large code block.

Comment: If the error really appears in the method you provide, I would say that `outOfScope` is a member-function of `List` but is not `const`-qualified, thus you cannot call it from a `const`-qualified member function. But we would need the declaration / definition of `outOfScope` to help you precisely...

Comment: Dear Holt, outOfScope is not a member of class List. It is declared in different header file and is being used here. The definition is as follows:

Comment: If you use a more sensible name than `s` for the size, or just call `size` after making it const, you don't need to sprinkle around comments explaining what it is.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<s; i++)` what is `s` ? in this for ?

Comment: @Ujjwal If `outOfScope` is not a member function, then I don't see how your code could create such error. Again, provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added the missing members and a trivial use, and [there's no problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a043ff7a5fe6bf4). As has been noted already, post a [mcve].

Comment: Now it's a massive submission most of which is assuredly not necessary to reproduce the problem. This tells us that you have not performed the steps described in the article [MCVE] that you were linked to, which are important/key aspects of debugging, and we do expect you to do that first.

Comment: @Holt I have added the complete code. Please have a look

Comment: @Ujjwal That's better but your code compiles fine, so the error is likely on the calling side. Try to create and example that **reproduces** your error (e.g., adding a list declaration and a call to `findAll()` that does not compile). Also, most of your code is irrelevant to the question, try making it **minimal** (remove the comparison operator, the irrelevant constructors/assignments operator, the methods that are not used). You can also add only the declaration of the methods you use but works fine (e.g., `insertAtEnd`).

Comment: @Holt corrected as per your recommendations. I have posted the implementation code too. Please have a look!

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for valuable suggestions. I will take care of it next time!

Comment: @rafix07 s is the size of the list. The whole code is now uploaded. Kindly have a look! Thanks

Comment: Start with making `const` the inherently non-modifying functions (`size`, `find`, `lookup`). Remove the constructor and assignment that take a non-const parameter.

Comment: @Ujjwal I've created a more standard version of your code with some extra comments, feel free to take a look at it: https://gist.github.com/Holt59/0a9bc4bf327598daf3b841ee7a17bbad

Comment: @Holt Thanks Holt! I learnt a lot the way you have done it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
List<int> findList = rollNo.findAll(rollNo[2]);
```

...you are calling the copy constructor of `List<int>` that takes a `const`-reference:

```
List(const List<T>& l)
```

In this constructor, you try to access the size of `l`:

```
s = l.size();
```

...but you cannot because `l` is `const`-qualified and `size()` is not, and you can only call `const`-qualified method on `const`-qualified variables.

To fix this, you need to `const`-qualify `size()`:

```
int size() const { return s; }
```

---

Here are some advice for your code, try to lookup a good recent C++ book for more:

- unless it is an exercice, **do not make your own `List`, use `std::vector`**;
- use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`;
- do not provide constructor or assignment operators that take non-constant lvalue-reference (`List(List<T>&)` and `operator=(List<T>&)`;
- provide move-constructor and move-assignment operator (`List(List<T>&&)` and `operator=(List<T>&&)`), see the [rule of 0/3/5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29);
- return `List<T>&` from your assignment operators;
- check the [copy-and-swap](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap) idiom for your assignment operators;
- `const`-qualify the function that should be: `size()`, `find()`, `lookup()`;
- add `const`-qualified overload for the relevant method: `const T& operator[](int i) const`;
- check some C++ utility functions, such as [`copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [`equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).

Comment: I'd move the last (most important) bullet point to the top